# How to set password policy in Active directory or OPenDS

Tags: active-directory, opends

i Want to set a policy in Microsoft active directory that it should prompt user to change password after 1st login with temporary password. If this can be done in OpenDs/LDAP it would help.

In active directory I want to set password complexity as well. I want to edit the current complexity setting to make it more complex apart from default.

I have tried setting with OpenDs guide but this has not helped for all setting. For openDs i could not ensure that password should expire after every 90 days if user does not change it. User should get the notifications 15 days prior to it. Also should prompt user to change password on first login or account gets locked after 1st use.

Answer (score 0):

Go the control panel and navigate to people node to set rules. Although all the advance rules are not possible but basic rules like session time out and simple password complexity is not possible.